# How to handle request when destroyRecord in Ember is called?

Tags: ember.js

When calling destroyRecord on Ember data model, it sends an ajax request to find the deleted record. This results in this error "Attempted to handle event `loadingData` on  while in state root.deleted.inFlight. Called with {_id: 832, _label: Fetching visit with id: 490725...."

The header request url on the ajax call is http://testing.localhost.com:3000/api/visits/490725 --> 490725 is the record I am deleting.

Any possible way to not send this request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, why would you want to not sent this request? You need to notify your server about the deletion. Its a `DELETE` request, not a `GET` request. You get the error because you return a response. As [you can see here](http://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-deleting) you should return only a top level meta element, or a `204 No Content`.

However its easy to prevent the request. Just [override `deleteRecord`.](https://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Adapter.html#method_deleteRecord) If you just do something like `return Ember.RSVP.resolve(undefined);` ember-data will just assume that every deletion is done.

Comment: Yes, I realized that the problem here was on the backend (how the request is being handled) rather than the front end (the request itself). Thank you!